# unexpected '}' while using laravel where grouping

Tags: laravel

I am getting

> syntax error: unexpected '}'

right after ->where('to_user_id', $to_user_id). I have bolded the one where I am getting error. I am passing the variables from a function. I only need help with this syntax error.

```php
 $results = DB::table('chat_messages')
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($from_user_id, $to_user_id)
                    {
                        $query->where('from_user_id', $from_user_id)
                          ->where('to_user_id', $to_user_id)
                    **}**)
                        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from_user_id, $to_user_id)
                     {
                        $query->where('from_user_id', $to_user_id)
                            ->where('to_user_id', $from_user_id)
                    })
                        ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon ; after the statement, it should be `$query->where(...)->where(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, just missing semicolons:

```
$results = DB::table('chat_messages')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($from_user_id, $to_user_id)
                {
                    $query->where('from_user_id', $from_user_id)
                      ->where('to_user_id', $to_user_id); //here
                })
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from_user_id, $to_user_id)
                 {
                    $query->where('from_user_id', $to_user_id)
                        ->where('to_user_id', $from_user_id); // here
                })
                    ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```